# PyobjC: how get NSButton attributes?

Tags: python, xcode, pyobjc

With little sign of a python, interested here PyObjC, I drew a simple calculator in Interface Builder, write a simple code, and the question arose - how to get the attributes NSButton?
dir() produces absolutely nothing, if it is not an object at all. Please tell me how to get the value of a button...

Comment: What do you mean with "the value of a button"?   You can use Apple's framework documentation to get information about the API for a class, PyObjC uses the same method names with a small translation: all colons in the method name are replaced with underscores.